# How can I exclude AssetHandler messages from the log in SvelteKit?

Tags: vite, sveltekit

How do I control the logging in SvelteKit? The AssetHandler is spewing out so many messages I can't see anything.

It seems these are just the assethandler doing its job.

I'm using SvelteKit 1.26.0 with Vite 4.4.11

e.g.

```
DEB | [ExternalAssetHandler] Loading 'http://localhost:5173/src/routes/status/+page.svelte?svelte&type=style&lang.css'
DEB | [AssetHandler] Handling request '/src/lib/css/grid.css' (file='src/lib/css/grid.css')
DEB | [AssetHandler] File 'src/lib/css/grid.css' not found, serving '/src/lib/css/grid.css' by AssetHandler
DEB | [AssetHandler] Handling request '/src/lib/images/laptop.svg' (file='src/lib/images/laptop.svg')
DEB | [AssetHandler] File 'src/lib/images/laptop.svg' not found, serving '/src/lib/images/laptop.svg' by AssetHandler
DEB | [AssetHandler] Handling request '/src/lib/images/laptop-x.svg' (file='src/lib/images/laptop-x.svg')
DEB | [AssetHandler] File 'src/lib/images/laptop-x.svg' not found, serving '/src/lib/images/laptop-x.svg' by AssetHandler
DEB | [ExternalAssetHandler] Loading 'http://localhost:5173/src/lib/css/grid.css'
DEB | [ExternalAssetHandler] Loading 'http://localhost:5173/src/lib/images/laptop.svg?import&component'
DEB | [ExternalAssetHandler] Loading 'http://localhost:5173/src/lib/images/laptop-x.svg?import&component'
```

``